# Excel-VBA How to access the contentDocumment using WebBrowser

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to access the document object of a frame with JS using WebBrowser. The code below works perfectly, but I need to use WebBrowser instead.
This is the error I've got:

> Run-time error '438'
>
> > Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> Any guidance please?

```
Sub GrabWorkerId1()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "my url"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Open "c:\temp\GrabWorkerId2.log" For Output As #3

    Write #3, objIE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(1).contentDocument.getElementsbyTagName("select")(0).innerhtml

    Close 3

    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Perhaps the issue is related the **Close** method and the related method to access the html elements.

First, please try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the website contains the iframe tag and the select element, and check the account. According to your code, the page should contain at least two iframe tag and the iframe content page will contains at least one select element, please verify it. Also, you could add a debugger from the VBA script, and check the innerhtml value, make sure you could get the value.

Second, about the **Close** method, try to modify the code as below:

```
Close #3
```

Besides, please check the following code, I have tested it on my side, it works well (the website contains one iframe tag, and the iframe content page just contains one select element):

```
Sub GrabWorkerId1()

    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "<website url>"

    While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
    Wend

    Open "d:\temp\test.log" For Output As #3

    Write #3, objIE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsbyTagName("select")(0).innerhtml

    Close #3

    Set objIE = Nothing   
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Zhi, sorry, I might have been not clear in my request. The code I've shared works smothly if I use IE object. I need to use WebBrowser instead and there is when I get the error. Something like this:         `webbrowser.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsbyTagName("select")(0).innerhtml`   Regarding the Close method you are right, but it works equally whithout the #. Thanks.

Comment: Could explain more details about the webbrowser, do you mean the [webbrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8)? Whether it still using VBA, can you share the related code to reproduce the problem?